# Blank login window using Mac Bot Framework Emulator

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-active-directory, botframework

Authentication bot signin outputs a blank window. I'm using the following bot ([here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/18.bot-authentication)). I get a response from the bot, but when I press 'Sign In' I get an empty Sign In prompt.

The Json inspector outputs:

```
{
  "attachments": [
    {
      "content": {
        "buttons": [
          {
            "text": "Please Sign In",
            "title": "Sign In",
            "type": "openUrl",
            "value": "oauthlink://&&&31b771b0-1111-11e9-bf2f-c5deac39c0ba|livechat"
          }
        ],
        "connectionName": "oauth_name",
        "text": "Please Sign In"
      },
      "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.oauth"
    }
  ],
  "channelId": "emulator",
  "conversation": {
    "id": "blah blah |livechat"
  },
  "entities": [],
  "from": {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Bot",
    "role": "bot"
  },
  "id": "blah blah",
  "inputHint": "expectingInput",
  "localTimestamp": "2019-01-28T14:59:22-05:00",
  "locale": "",
  "recipient": {
    "id": "bath blah",
    "role": "user"
  },
  "replyToId": "blah blah",
  "serviceUrl": "http://localhost:49276",
  "timestamp": "2019-01-28T19:59:22.359Z",
  "type": "message"
}
```

Here is an image of the conversation:
[image]

Here is an image of the blank 'Sign In' prompt:
[image]

Any idea of what could be causing this ?

I'm on a Mac running MacOS: 10.13.6

Bot Framework Emulator: Version 4.2.1 (4.2.1.45654)

Visual Studio 2017 for Mac Version 7.7.3 build 43

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this is Mac specific; this is a bug in the emulator in general. [I started reporting the issue in the comments of another issue here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator/issues/1212#issuecomment-455694768) because I wasn't sure if they were "done" fixing the original issue yet, but it's apparent that this is a whole new issue that they need to address.

[I have filed the issue here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator/issues/1268) if you want to track it. Please feel free to upvote or add more details.

Answer (score 1):

I can see in your picture that ngrok is not configured for the emulator. Please connect ngrok to the emulator in the 'settings' tab of the emulator, and it should solve this problem!

Comment: I've also tried it with it configured. In the settings page I have the path to ngrok and in Azure Bot Channels Registration I have the messaging end point as `https://11a111a1.ngrok.io/api/messages` and my emulator logs are as follows: `[15:06:55]Emulator listening on http://localhost:49178
[15:06:55]ngrok listening on https://11a111a1.ngrok.io
[15:06:55]ngrok traffic inspector:http://127.0.0.1:4040
[15:06:55]Will use ngrok for local addresses`